# ChartJS v3 Migration: how to define annotation plugin?

Tags: annotations, chart.js

I'm trying to migrate a `Chart.js` html file created using version 2.7.1

My first problem is how to replace first script found at begin of my `HTML` file

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
```

I have already replaced first script named `Chart.min.js` by following line

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

I'm surprise that version number has been removed from script name but it is what is rated on `Chart.js` web site.

Now I try to find `Annotation` plugin but I don't find any script reference on the Web.

Where can I find `Annotation` plugin on the web and use it without installing this file on my PC ?

If what I search is impossible, how can I do to continue to use `Annotation` plugin ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the lib name in the search bar of the cdn

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/chartjs-plugin-annotation

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.0.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js" integrity="sha512-sAqZojh+v9iWel74NtgLdr9y2QWsy+kfFfffU9Gzgcrg6SmNDLIznMTyZIFo33dDcRMhYV9HGCDbaTVXxUwz7g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I have added your reference and annotation visible in V2 version is now visible in V3 version. I have just added SRC attribute !